Error: com.android.tools.build:gradle not set in build.gradle after migrating to Plugin DSL in Flutter
I'm encountering an issue after migrating my Flutter project to use Gradle's Plugin DSL syntax for applying plugins. I've followed the migration guide, but I'm still seeing the following error:
* Where:
Build file 'flutter/android/build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > com.android.tools.build:gradle is not set in the build.gradle file
      > com.android.tools.build:gradle is not set in the build.gradle file

Project Setup
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
    id "com.huawei.agconnect"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(System.properties['user.home'] + '/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

       
    }

    compileSdkVersion 34

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
     

        signingConfig signingConfigs.'release-signing'
        resConfigs "en", "zh-rCN", "ar"
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        huawei {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Alriyada"]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.'release-signing'
            aaptOptions {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!mlkit_pose:!mlkit_label_default_model:'
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/**/libtranslate_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libdigitalink.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libxeno_native.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libmlkitcommonpipeline.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libbarhopper_v2.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libclassifier_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libface_detector_v2_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/libtensorflowlite_jni.so'
        exclude 'lib/**/liblanguage_id_jni.so'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.9.0.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.11.0.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:hmscoreinstaller:6.7.0.300'
}

googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "com.huawei.agconnect") {
                useModule("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.0.300")
            }
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.huawei.agconnect' version '1.9.0' apply false
}

include ':app'

build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Additional Information:
Flutter version: 3.16.0
Gradle version: 7.4.2
Kotlin version: 1.9.0
Android Gradle Plugin version: 7.4.2
I've ensured that com.android.tools.build:gradle is included in the settings.gradle and app/build.gradle files as per the new Plugin DSL syntax. However, the error persists. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

I'm seeing you have google services and crashlytics. Did you perform the steps in the migration guide related to them as well? Reference.

@tomerpacific, Yes
